# How to add class to the third <li> element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add class for the third element in javascript. I have this structure:

```
<ul class="products-grid row four-columns first">
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item add-class-here"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
$( "ul.products-grid li:nth-child(3)").addClass("new_css_class");
```

Reference : https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 3):

```
$("ul.products-grid li").eq(2).addClass("classname");
```

This code is for adding class to 3rd li element. You can use eq similarly for any element.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function doActive(ind) {
    var nItem = document.querySelector("#Folder_A li:nth-child(" + ind + ")");
    //select nth child under id 'Folder_A'
    nItem.classList.add("active");
    //Add class 'active' to nth child
}

doActive(3);
//or Call 'doActive' function onclick
```

```css
#Folder_A li {
  padding: 12px;
}
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ol id="Folder_A">
    <li>FileName 1</li>
    <li>FileName 2</li>
    <li>FileName 3</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Good point for using querySelector instead of jQuery and try to make this function with a position parameter. I think you are replacing all classes actually by affecting your class to className attribute. You can use classList instead https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
Also you should consider using the HTML provided by OP to demonstrate your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with regular javascript.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
items[2].className += " hello";
```

A shorter version that I would actually use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item')[2].className += " hello";
```

Here you have a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/revem5uh/

---

Since you also tagged css, I wanted to let you know that there are selectors for doing this as well with css only.

```
li.item:nth-child(3){
  color: blue;
}
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try `eq()` and add class to third `li` as shown :-

```
$('ul.products-grid > li:eq(2)').addClass('classname')
```

```js
$('ul.products-grid > li.item:eq(2)').addClass('myclass')
```

```css
.myclass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="products-grid row four-columns first">
  <li class="item">item</li>
  <li class="item">item</li>
  <li class="item add-class-here">item</li>
  <li class="item">item</li>
</ul>
```